# Cutoffs to consider for survival tree

Tags: survival, cart, censoring

In an tree based algorithm a criterion is measured at certain cutoffs for the variable. This cutoffs are the candidate split points for that variable.

How does one come up with candidate split points for a variable in a survival tree? More specifically say, when you are using the log-rank test statistic between the left and right split samples as the criterion.

I am currently using only those cutoffs in the variable which correspond to failures.

Nothing specific is mentioned in "Regression Trees for Censored Data" by Mark Robert Segal.

Answer (score 1):

Such cutoffs are determined by doing a huge number of statistical tests, which results in major multiplicity problems.  Note that single tree methods require perhaps 50,000 - 100,000 subjects to yield reliable tree structure.  What is your sample size and number of events?